# Googlesheets: Colour Code range based on text, and hexcode

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Context:

- I've created a dynamic timetable for a set of events based on date
- For example, if I select date dd/mm/yy, it will show me all the events, and time slots they're allocated to

Challenge:

- Each event should be allocated to a set of colour which represent a category of events but I'm not able to wrap my head around of how to do that
- I tried writing an app script, but i'm horribly failing

Question:

- Could someone help with a script where range B6:R in the first tab colour codes based on the matching name of the event in column J, and the colour hexcode in column I in tab2? As I change the change dates in the drop-down, the colours should update.

Link to sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16T4isDidfTv5xs5xNJQvCRzIH4lc2y82NW_IqRsvagA/edit#gid=166765538

I would appreciate any help, tips :)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of your provided Spreadsheet. And, please run the function `sample`. By this, 6 conditional format rules are set to "B6:R" of "PROG BY VENUE" sheet.

```js
function sample() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("PROG BY VENUE");
  const sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Data_Validation");
  const colors = sheet2.getRange("I2:J" + sheet2.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().reduce((o, [i, j]) => (o[i] = o[i] ? [...o[i], j] : [j], o), {});
  const range = sheet1.getRange("B6:R");
  const rules = Object.entries(colors).map(([k, v]) => SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule().setRanges([range]).whenFormulaSatisfied(`=REGEXMATCH(B6;"${v.join("|")}")`).setBackground(k).build());
  sheet1.clearConditionalFormatRules();
  sheet1.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}
```

#### Testing:

After this script was run when the dropdown list of "D1" of "PROG BY VENUE" sheet, the following result was obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your provided Spreadsheet. When you change the Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.
- In this case, when you update the values of "I2:J" of "Data_Validation" sheet, please run the above script again. By this, the conditional format rules are also updated.

#### References:

- [Class ConditionalFormatRuleBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder)
- [setConditionalFormatRules(rules)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setConditionalFormatRules(ConditionalFormatRule))

Comment: That is amazing! Thank you so much! It is running as intended!

Comment: @manonamission Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.